# Buttons using onClickListener

Tags: android

am new to android
I have seen many examples on creating buttons, but i just can't get what does each line mean :(
take the following piece of code as an ex.

```
   connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_connect) 
   connect.setOnClickListener(connectListener)
    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.i("CONNECT PRESSED", "press")
                          //  ....
                          //  ....
                          //  ....
    };
```

what i know is that the first line Defines a button, but wht is findViewbyId?
i know the second line
but then when defining the listener, what's the log.i?
nd r "connect pressed" and "press" just labels for the button? f so why there r two for a single button...

Comment: My dear, you need to have an Android book/PDF/tutorials in your Android.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/index.html is the best to learn about android

Comment: Study some of the tutorials and start programming

Answer (score 2):

You should have an additional `Button connect;` before those lines.

```
connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_connect) // findViewById() in layman term it means, finding view by id. Which also means finding the view(button/textview/edittext) by ID(value you stated in your main.xml for the view. e.e. android:id=@+id/"")

connect.setOnClickListener(connectListener) //listens to a click when clicked

private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() { //if button of android:id="button_connect" is clicked, Do this method.
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("CONNECT PRESSED", "press") //prints message in your logcat
                      //  ....
                      //  ....
                      //  ....
};
```

If you still don't understand what does findViewById(), just think of it this way. View is man. Id is name. So in the end you are finding the man by name("Whatever this is")

Answer (score 0):

In Android you normally define the layout of an Activity in an XML file. Each View element in a layout that you want to interact with in code needs an id. In you example the layout XML file needs to have a button with the id `button_connect`.

In the onCreate() method of an Activity you normally call setContentView() and pass it the layout you want to use in this Activity. E.g. `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);` where your layout file's name is my_layout.xml.

The setContentView() method builds up the defined layout as objects and with `findViewById(R.id.button_connect)` you get a reference to a Button object from this layout whose id is `button_connect`.

`Log.i()` is simply logs the message "press" under the tag "CONNECT PRESSED" in the log cat.

Answer (score 0):

It seem to be you didn't read basic things about android app development. Android Developers website providing information to learn android app development with good examples and tutorials. You are asking very basic things by just copying the code from tutorials.

Actually its not the right place for this kind of questions. First do practice by reading tutorials around the web.

Coming to your doubts regarding code you posted here, those are very basic things.

1. findViewById() finds a View by field Id, which is declared in XML layout file as below
2. Log.i() is LogCat info message displayed in your logcat window when debugging is enabled in your app.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you probably have defined an `xml` layout file as the style of your activity with `setContentView(R.layout.myXMLLayout);`

If not, findViewById(R.id.button_connect) will fail.
`R.id.button_connect` refers to an `id` created in your `xml` layout.
There has to be a line `android:id="@+id/button_connect"` in a `< Button >` tag.

`findViewById` finds this Button (which is more genereally a `view`, which is why you have to cast it to a `Button` with the `(Button)` before findViewById(...) ). You then refer to exactly the button you've put in your xml.

`Log.i("CONNECT PRESSED","press");` isn't necessary at all. It's just `logging` the press of the button and displays it in the `log cat`. It can be removed without any further impact. This is for debugging only and should be removed for any final (public) versions of your code.